# Migrated Posts gets downvote cleared but reputation not restored?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration

I posted a slightly off-topic post in Super User, got downvoted, then admin migrated my post to Stack Overflow, although the downvote has been cleared, but my deducted reputation wasn't restored. is this normal?

Comment: Downvotes always sting a little, but they're part of the learning process. I've had my fair share of them, and downvotes when I was a low-level participant here hurt a lot more than they do now. Don't let them dissuade you from participating, but do learn from them.

Answer (score 9):

It is normal. The original question (now a [migration stub](https://superuser.com/posts/1217126/revisions)) is still here.

While the question exists here it has a downvote on it. That downvote counts.  Downvotes on questions do not get migrated, but they do get left behind.

If the question is deleted on this site then it *should* reverse the downvote, but we don't immediately delete migrated questions so that the history can be seen. The [roomba](https://superuser.com/help/roomba) clears up these migration stubs after a while as well, another reason why we don't worry too much about clearing up in this case.

It's only one downvote though.

Comment: Do you mean after some time the remaining question on superuser would get automatically deleted and rep along with the downvote would be restored?

Comment: Yes,  believe that is what should happen.